# why is php written in HTML file since HTML is loaded and run on server side, but PHP only on server side?

Tags: php, html

i don't understand why is PHP embedded in HTML when its only running on server side and HTML file is loaded in to the browser on client side.. ?

Comment: It it is really the other way around, HTML is embedded in PHP. PHP outputs the HTML

Comment: The opening tags of PHP tell the web server that the code within the tags should be processed by PHP engine and not be considered HTML code. This is why it's fine to use inline PHP in HTML.

Comment: thank you very much Nikos! i dident know that 
<?php
?>
have that roll...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a server side language which can be, and very often is, used for pre-processing of the output from the server to the client. When the client asks the server for a particular page, for example a product detail page, a calendar or a blog article, PHP will get the data to use on that page from a database or other storage technology and send to the client.

Now if PHP is putting that data into the HTML on the server, the client receives an HTML document complete with all the data as well as the document structure, HTML tags and, unless hosted in separate files,  CSS styles and Javascript code.

The most basic way for PHP to do this is inlining the HTML like so in a `.php` file:

```
<h1><?php echo "Hello World!";?></h1>
```

Which will produce HTML for the client that looks like:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Which will display as:

## Hello World!

In this very simple example it might be hard to see the benefits, but as soon as you start using dynamic data, perhaps as simple as displaying the current day or showing some other piece of information that changes, you can see the benefit of using something like PHP for that task.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will only process things that are enclosed within one of its valid code blocks (such as `<?php` and `?>`). Because of this, PHP effectively ignores everything that it was not specifically told to process and can be used to our advantage. For example, what will the output from the following be?

```
<?php
$var = 5;
?>

$var = 10;<br />
The variable $var has a value of: <?=$var?><br />
```

Is this a valid script? Yes, the output would be the following:

```
$var = 10;
The variable $var has a value of: 5
```

Notice that with the second assignment of `$var`, when we attempt to change the value from 5 to 10, it has no effect because it is not enclosed within valid PHP code-block syntax. So, instead of being processed, it is simply displayed to the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create, say a php file that contains HTML with embedded PHP, and the browser client asks your server for that file, your entire file is still on the server and untouched.

But right before the file is delivered to the requesting user, the file is processed (if you have your server to process .php files, that is) and the embedded PHP is replaced with it's output. Usually, the embeded PHP code never reaches the browser client, only the processed file does.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine reading an html file like a book. The language of the book is html. A webserver, such as apache, takes the html code and sends it to the user. It is your browser that interprets it. What your browser receives is pure text.

Now, the apache has a PHP extension. So, when the webserver reads the html code, and suddenly stumbles upon < ?php ?> tags, it does not send it to the user. Instead, it sends it to the PHP server.

The PHP server processes the code and returns back only pure html code. Then everything is sent over to the user.